# Modify object's geometry after animation has been applied

Tags: animation, geometry

I have just made some animation on object (applied some Rot, Scale, Transform keys on different frames so object is performing motion) and suddenly it is understood that object must have some other proportions (a little bit more). The question is: how to change geometry of such an object without affecting (remove, change or other actions) all animation keys?

Comment: This depends on how you animated the object. If it's just simple transformations, you should be able to edit  it and have it behave fine, if it has any deformation, it might be a bit tricky or next to impossible. If you could share the blend file, we might be better able to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can use is to parent it to an **Empty** object. Any transformation to an object will affect any other object parented to it, compounding their own transformation without needing to change any single keyframe. And an Empty is the simplest to setup as the parent, for such purpose.